# Angular 7 on nodeJS server referencing github

Tags: node.js, angular, github, angular7

I have an angular 7 app that runs on NodeJS server. When I build my app from local and deployed it, it works fine.

However, after I committed the project to github, another developer cloned it. He created the build for NodeJS server, and now all the paths are pointing to github.

[Screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XBQV.png)

Did anyone experience the same? Please advise how to fix it.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense, and we can't troubleshoot code we can't see. Pushing code to GitHub, cloning from GitHub, etc. have no effect on the files themselves. Are you and your friend running the code in exactly the same way?

Comment: yes, we use the same ng build command. Moreover, we are using VS Code if it makes a difference.